# What does a 3D periodic solution of a differential equation look like?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

The Pointcare-Bendixson Theorem implies that if a solution stays in a bounded region with no equilibrium points then it is either a periodic solution or it approaches a periodic orbit as t goes to infinity. But this is only in 2D. In higher order dimensions, are we able to find that solutions are periodic solution or approaching a periodic solution in that higher dimension space?

Comment: No. As you would find by reading the Wikipedia article [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem).

Comment: Bonus Wikipedia link: [Lorenz system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your question a little unclear.
Of course, we *can* find periodic solutions to many 3D (and higher dimensional) systems.  However, we can't conclude that there *must* be such orbits simply because they are bounded.  Let's examine the possibilities using the famous Lorenz equations:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 x'(t)=\sigma  (y(t)-x(t)) \\
 y'(t)=x(t) (\rho -z(t))-y(t) \\
 z'(t)=x(t) y(t)-\beta \,  z(t) \\
\end{array}
$$
Note that $\sigma$, $\rho$, and $\beta$ are parameters.  We'll let $\sigma=10$, $\beta=8/3$, and consider several values of $\rho$.

I guess the most famous choice of $\rho$ is $\rho=28$. Solving the system numerically starting with an initial condition close to (but not exactly at) the origin leads to the following picture:

[image]

The path is colored by time.  The fact that the colors are so spread out indicates the chaos inherent in the system.  This is an example of exactly what *cannot* occur in the 2D case; the solution is bounded but not periodic.

For smaller values of $\rho$, there are attractive equilibria.  In addition to being periodic, the attractive nature answers your question about whether or not we might hope to *approach* a periodic orbit.  For $\rho=13$, we get something like so:

[image]

Finally, here's an amazing periodic orbit for $\rho=99.65$:

[image]

This orbit is periodic and it's trajectory traces out a torus knot in space.  Obviously, this kind of behavior can't happen in the plane.  It's actually not too difficult to find this sort of orbit using numerical techniques.  A proof of the periodicity and knotting behavior is more difficult but can be found [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~jb/bw-KPO-I.pdf).